# Delegated constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(int n, char c, bool b) 
        /* : some complex initialization list that you don't want to repeat. */
        {initialize();}
    A(int n) : A(n, default_char, default_bool) {}
    A(char c) : A(default_int, c, default_bool) {}  // Do not want initialize() called!
    A(bool b) : A(default_int, default_char, b) {}
    A(int n, char c) : A(n, c, default_bool) {}
    A(int n, bool b) : A(n, default_char, b) {}  // Do not want initialize() called!
    A(char c, bool b) : A(default_int, c, b) {}
private:
    static const int default_int = 3;
    static const char default_char = 't';
    static const bool default_bool = true;
    void initialize() {std::cout << "A ctor.\n";}
};

int main() {
    A a(5,'a',false);
    A b(5);
    A c('a');
    A (5,'a');
    A (5,false);
    A ('a',false);
}
```

Assume I do NOT want `initialize();` to be called for some of the constructors (e.g. stated in the code).  How to avoid that without repeating the "complex initialization list" of `A(int,char,bool)` 's constructor (so as to avoid future maintenance issues)?

Comment: If you have many complex initialisation lists, your class needs to be broken up.

Comment: @ Barry.  Ok my first question may be a duplicate, but what about the second question then?  I'll edit my question so that only the second question is asked.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate - that question doesn't address the initialize() method.

Comment: Why don't you want to initialise in some instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30561530/2069064) for most of the solution. Once we have that, we can have:

```
template <typename DoInit>
A(int n, char c, bool b, DoInit do_init) 
/* : some complex initialization list that you don't want to repeat. */
{
    maybe_initialize(DoInit{});
}

void maybe_initialize(std::false_type ) { }
void maybe_initialize(std::true_type ) {
    /* stuff */
}
```

And so, we have the general case where we *do* want initialization:

```
template <typename ... Ts, typename std::enable_if_t<detail::is_included<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Year, Month, Day>> ::value>* = nullptr>
A(Ts... ts) :
    A(get_or_default<int>(std::tie(ts...)),
      get_or_default<char>(std::tie(ts...)),
      get_or_default<bool>(std::tie(ts...)),
      std::true_type{})
{}
```

And then a bunch of cases where we *don't* want it:

```
A(char c)
: A(default_int, c, default_bool, std::false_type{})
{ }

A(int n, bool b)
: A(n, default_char, b, std::false_type{})
{ }
```

If there are a *lot* of such cases, you could add a similar sort of `enable_if_t` condition for a variadic template constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You can give your class a private constructor to which all the public constructors delegate.  Here, the first argument determines whether to initialise:

```
private:
    A(bool do_initialize, int n, char c, bool b)
        /* initialisers */
    { if (do_initialize) initialize(); }

public:
    A(int n, char c, bool b) : A(true, n, c, b) {}
    A(int n) : A(true, n, default_char, default_bool) {}
    A(char c) : A(false, default_int, c, default_bool) {}  // Do not want initialize() called!
    A(bool b) : A(true, default_int, default_char, b) {}
    A(int n, char c) : A(true, n, c, default_bool) {}
    A(int n, bool b) : A(false, n, default_char, b) {}  // Do not want initialize() called!
    A(char c, bool b) : A(true, default_int, c, b) {}
```