# passing arguments to a c++ function without specific order

Tags: c++, function, overloading

let's say i have a function foo, that takes two non-primitive object of different types ,e.g:

```
void foo(House h, Dog d) {// implementation  }
```

assuming that placement of  these arguments has no effect on the function output then foo(h,d) = foo (d,h) theoretically. but c++ does not allow this unless I overload this function by:

```
void foo (Dog d, House h) {// implementation   }
```

but this overloading becomes a pain in the butt if the number of arguments increases (e.g. 6 overloading for 3 arguments and so on).

my question is, is there any easy way to acheive the conveniece of passing arguments not in a specific order without repetative overloading?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would anyone want to pass parameters to a function in a wrong order?

Comment: Why do you need this flexibility? If you construct it, you can pass them in the defined order.

Comment: if you know the function takes 3 different type of arguments, wouldn't be convenient to be able pass them in any order rather than checking the function prototyoe?

Comment: Encapsulate all these arguments in an object and pass the object reference to the function.

Comment: that's not the point! mathematically speaking if the output of f(x,y) is the same as f(y,x), why should i concern about the correct order of the arguments?

Comment: encapsulation maybe helpful but also redundant. isn't it? it just adds an extra layer of rather useless complication.

Comment: @Arash so does having some heavily templated generic fluff just to give you the luxury of some mathematical theorem at the cost of software engineering for reasoning and maintainability. It's still interesting as an exercise though.

Comment: good point Paul, I don't know how to acheive this in a nice and clean way, otherwise I would not ask. it seems to me this should be the job of compiler to take care of these details instead of forcing the user to follow specific function prototypes.

Comment: Your understanding of mathematical functions is rather shallow. In mathematics,  a function is defined as a mapping from an _ordered_ tuple, so even if f (x,y) incidentally equals f (y,x), it does not mean that the order of arguments is not important.

Comment: thank you for your comment DYZ. i think i know enough about mathematical principles of functions.  if f(x,y)=(x+y) then f(y,x) is the same as f(x,y) and it's not incidental. you don't believe me plug any two numbers.

Comment: It wouldn't hold if `f` were division or subtraction though would it? Is 10 % 2 == 2 % 10 or is 5 - 2 == 2 - 5??

Comment: of course not Paul. thats because the operator% or opeator/ (read them function%() or function/() ) does not behave symmetrically when it comes to two arguments. another problem with these example is that these are two premitive types and of course compiler has no clue what to do unless you pass the arguments in correc order.

Comment: again let's asume the so-called foo (House h, Dog d) function is supposed to do something as stupid and simple as paint House h and feed dog d. would it be different if I first feed the dog and then paint the house? if the placement of arguments have no effect on the outcome, why should it important at all? I know python support this behavior, I was just looking to see if someone knows how to do this in c++.

Comment: Related to [c-how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561407/c-how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads)

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible to re-order n arguments with O(n) wrappers:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A { int a; A(int a) : a(a) {} };
struct B { int b; B(int b) : b(b) {} };
struct C { int c; C(int c) : c(c) {} };
struct D { int d; D(int d) : d(d) {} };
static void foo(A a, B b, C c, D d) { cout << a.a << " " << b.b << " " << c.c << " " << d.d << endl; }
template<class ...Args> struct Foo { void operator()(Args...); };
template<class ...Args> static void foo(Args ...args) { Foo<Args...>()(args...); }
template<class T, class U> struct Foo<T, U, C, D> { void operator()(T t, U u, C c, D d) { foo(u, t, c, d); } };
template<class T, class U, class V> struct Foo<T, U, V, D> { void operator()(T t, U u, V v, D d) { foo(v, t, u, d); } };
template<class T, class U, class V, class W> struct Foo<T, U, V, W> { void operator()(T t, U u, V v, W w) { foo(w, t, u, v); } };
int main() {
    foo(A(1), B(2), C(3), D(4));
    foo(D(5), C(6), B(7), A(8));
    return 0;
}
```

(The wrapper class `Foo` is required because functions cannot be partially specialized.)

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 a.cc
$ ./a.out
1 2 3 4
8 7 6 5
```

Do not construe this as an endorsement of this technique. Rather: even if it's possible, please don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17, we have `std::get<T>(std::tuple)`. This can be combined with `std::forward_as_tuple`:

```
template< typename ... unordered_arg >
void foo( std::tuple< unordered_arg ... > arg_set ) {
    House h = std::get< House && >( std::move( arg_set ) );
    Dog d = std::get< Dog && >( std::move( arg_set ) );

    // implementation
}

template< typename ... arg >
void foo( arg ... a )
    { foo_impl( std::forward_as_tuple( std::move( a ) ... ) ); }
```

(It's alright to multiply do `move(arg_set)` as long as a mutually-exclusive part of it is accessed each time.)

Comment: The tuple contains references, and you try to `get` bare  types out. You'll have to write your own `get` that decays types in the tuple before trying to match them to its parameter for this approach to work.

Comment: @yurikilochek Thanks, fixed. (Instead of reimplementing/shimming `get`, I switched to pass-by-value.)

Comment: I really like your answer. The only problem I can see is that it's UB if you have the same type twice because of how `std::get` works. Am I wrong? This could be a strong constraint.

Comment: @skypjack That's a compile-time error according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get). There's no rule for repetitions in the permutations here, so failure by default seems like a good behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is better to reduce the number of parameters passed to a function. There are two ways to do what you want.

- Create a class which has these non primitive data as member variables. Once these members are initiliazed, you can call a member function which operates on these member data
- Encapsulate these non primitive data in an object and pass this object by reference to your function.

Either way you don't need to worry about the *order of arguments* as long as all arguments are initialized.

Comment: i agree that encapsulation might be a solution, but making a class or structure for each stand alone function is just not practical. is it? maybe I am wrong or maybe  i asked a bad question.

Comment: No, I am not advocating to create a class or structure for each stand alone function. Basically, you need to identify which functions operate on which data and is there a scope to club together these data in an encapsulated format so that you have related member functions operating on the data they are interested in. Also, another thing to note is generally a class or a function should have single responsibility.

Comment: In which order do you pass the arguments to the constructor of this class you want him to make?

Comment: @user12341234, in such a case, constructor may be used to default construct the members and OP may have to depend on Setter functions to finish initialization.

Answer (score 0):

[As far as I can tell](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/python-style-keyword-args-in-c-good-practice-or-bad-idea), there does not seem to be a way to replicate Python-style keyword arguments in C++ (beyond the ways listed in the provided Software Engineering thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using hierarchy to do that as this example

```
class Object
{
public:
    enum Type { Dog, House};
    Type m_type;
};

class Dog : public Object
{

};

class House : public Object
{

};

void myFunction(const Object& a, const Object& b)
{

}
```

If needed you can recast the object using m_type within myFunction or implement global function on the parent class.

Another way might be to use templates.

Comment: This throws away any notion of compile time safety. You'd need dynamic_casts to retrieve the types.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any easy way to acheive the conveniece of passing arguments not in a specific order without repetative overloading?

Yes, you can do this, but because you haven't said what is your exact usage of this function I am not able to give you general purpose solution to this. Anyway, for all people claiming in the comments that behavior which is needed by the author of the question is wrong, bad, stupid etc, please consider following piece of code, which works and I see potential in this.

Let's assume that we have a class which has fields which store some values and we want to have a setters (and probably getters as well) to access those values (for the clarity I presented only minimum version).

So, this class would be:

```
struct A {
    int g1 {};
    int g2 {};
    int g3 {};
};
```

This class does not have setters or getters because we are going to wrap it in different class, a `Data` class.

```
struct Data {
    template <typename... Ts>
    void set (Ts&&... ts) {
        set_impl (std::forward<Ts> (ts)...);
    }

    A a;
private:
    template <typename T>
    void set_impl (T&& t) {
        a.*T::mem = t.v; // (X)
    }

    template <typename T, typename K, typename... Ts>
    void set_impl (T&& t, K&& k, Ts&&... ts) {
        set_impl (std::forward<T> (t));
        set_impl (std::forward<K> (k), std::forward<Ts> (ts)...);
    }
};
```

So here we have a class which has `set` member function which takes arbitrary number or arguments and each of them can be (and in this example should be) of different type. To set `A` fields like you see in `(X)` you need to pass an object of type which has a pointer to `A` member. So please take a look at the following classes.

```
struct G {
    G (int c = {}) : v {c} {}

    int v;
};

struct G1 : G { using G::G; static constexpr int A::* mem = &A::g1; };
struct G2 : G { using G::G; static constexpr int A::* mem = &A::g2; };
struct G3 : G { using G::G; static constexpr int A::* mem = &A::g3; };
```

All `Gx` functions are here only for setting the value of `A` fields and each of them knows which field is going to set.

Helper function for showing the result is:

```
void show (const A& v) {
    std::cout << "g1 = " << v.g1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "g2 = " << v.g2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "g3 = " << v.g3 << std::endl;
}
```

And finally, the usage:

```
Data d;
d.set (G1 {10}, G2 {20}, G3 {30});
show (d.a);

Data p;
p.set (G3 {40}, G1 {-30}, G2 {120});
show (p.a);
```

which gives us the output:

```
g1 = 10
g2 = 20
g3 = 30
g1 = -30
g2 = 120
g3 = 40
```

Like I said, I do not know if this fits your needs, but this is just an example how to do this and it maybe helpful for you.

Nonetheless putting values in not specified order (in conjunction with arbitrary number of values) has advantage that you can set only those values that are needed.