# Efficient construction delegation

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've been pondering constructor delegation and how to efficiently without code duplication construct.

Let's consider the following

**Code sample 101**

Def cons is delegated to but delegating constructors must pass in dummy empty values.  Problem is it is error prone and messy.

```
class A
{
    int a1;
    double a2;
    string a3;
    DatabaseHandle* p;

public:
    A(int i=0, double d=0.0, string s="") : a1(i), a2(d), a3(s) {
        //open data base connection
    }
    A(int i) : A(i) {}
    A(double d) : A(0,d) {}
    A(string s) : A(0,0.0,s) {}  
}
```

**Code sample 102**

Much cleaner syntax, but not as efficient as 101.  Delegating constructors re-assign value.

```
class A
{
    int a1;
    double a2;
    string a3;
    DatabaseHandle* p;

public:
    A(int i=0, double d=0.0, string s="") : a1(i), a2(d), a3(s) {
         //open database
    }
    A(int i) : A() { a1=i; }
    A(double d) : A() { a2=d;}
    A(string s) : A() { a3=s;}  
}
```

**Code sample 103**

No improvement over 102, in fact requires 1 extra constructor. So less code lean.

```
class A
{
    int a1 = 0;
    double a2 = 0.0;
    string a3 = "";
    DatabaseHandle* p;

public:
    A() { //open database
    }
    A(int i) : A() { a1=i; }
    A(double d) : A() { a2=d;}
    A(string s) : A() { a3=s;} 
    A(int i, double d, string s) : a1(i), a2(d), a3(s) {}
}
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to fix this code so that (1) there is little or no code repetition (2) Don't have to pass in dummy place holder values into constructor parameter (3) requires no re-assignment?

Assume that min C++ version is C++11.

**NOTE/EDIT:**
I added DatabaseHandle* p, to clarify that the def constructor has some logic to set things up.  I wanted to clarify that there is some common work to be done by constructors.  I apologize if this was not clear in original post.

Comment: Why don't you just do `A(int i):a1{i}{}` `A(double d):a2{d}{}` ... with member having default initializer as in 103?

Comment: You might look at [c-how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561407/c-how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads/30561530#30561530)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
class A  {
  int a1 = 0;
  double a2 = 0.0;
  std::string a3 = "";
  upDBHandle p = open_database(a1, a2, a3);
public:
  A() = default;
  explicit A(int i):a1(i) {}
  explicit A(double d):a2(d) {}
  explicit A(std::string s):a3(std::move(s)) {} 
  A(int i, double d, std::string s) : a1(i), a2(d), a3(std::move(s)) {}
};
```

assuming:

```
struct DatabaseHandle {};

using upDBHandle = std::unique_ptr<DatabaseHandle>;

upDBHandle open_database( int a, double d, std::string const& s ) {
  return std::make_unique<DatabaseHandle>();
}
```

or equivalent.

or:

```
struct A_settings {
  int a1 = 0;
  double a2 = 0.0;
  std::string a3 = "";
};

struct DatabaseHandle {};

using upDBHandle = std::unique_ptr<DatabaseHandle>;

upDBHandle open_database( int a, double d, std::string const& s ) {
  return std::make_unique<DatabaseHandle>();
}

class A  {
  A_settings settings;
  upDBHandle p = open_database(settings.a1, settings.a2, settings.a3);
public:
  A() = default;
  explicit A(A_settings s) : settings(std::move(s)) {}
};
```

callers can create various meaningful `A_settings` factory functions if they want to set some subset of fields.  If that isn't any good, you move the per-element ctors to it.

Comment: Thank you.  This solution does away with constructor delegation.  It is a good point that this can be so, but I wasn't clear enough in my op that there is some common work to be done by constructors.  In my haste to make example lean, I did not make this obvious.  I edited OP to make this more clear.

Comment: Thank you or using explicit.  I believe it is required in such a case since there is ambiguity between double and int.

Comment: hmmm... so I can write all sorts of logic code where the class members are declared with regards to the database logic?  All sorts of if checks, etc, in order to open the database?  It's interestinf approach, never seen code there like that.  Generally c++ code in classes is either in a method or constructor/destructor.  Is it good practice to have free floating code in a class?  Normally only declerations of members free-float in a class, no?

Comment: It seems we are trying to avoid constructor delegation at all cost.  Just trying to understand.

Comment: @code If a type is an aggregate, treat it like an aggregate.  If it is a resource handle, treat it like a resource handle.  It shouldn't be both.  This is the "rule of 0"; write neither destructors, copy/move assignment operators nor copy/move constructors.  I'd even stuff your random extra data into a public `struct` and make my ctor take *that* instead.

Comment: Interesting. Could you also show that as a code example?  Just to be clear.

Comment: would you say then that constructor delegation is best avoided?  Is there a valid use for it?

Comment: @code I didn't implement move/copy/etc above.  Rule of 0 is googleable.  There are valid uses for constructor delegation, I use it all the time.  For example, `span<int>( int*, std::size_t )` should delegate to `span<int>( int*, int* )`, as they are two ways of saying the same thing that are highly useful to have around.

Comment: Right, I meant code with regards to the struct and ctor comment.  I wasn't clear what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to chain to a default constructor for default member initializers to be applied. They'll have effect in any constructor which doesn't give them explicit initializers.

```
class A
{
    int a1 = 0;
    double a2 = 0.0;
    string a3 = "";

public:
    A() {}
    A(int i) : a1(i) {}
    A(double d) : a2(d) {}
    A(string s) : a3(s) {}
};
```

Comment: You no longer have possibility to set 2 or 3 member directly.

Comment: @Jarod42 Arbitrary subsets of initializers doesn't seem to be part of the OP's requirements.

Comment: Thank you.  This solution does away with constructor delegation.  It is a good point that this can be so, but I wasn't clear enough in my op that there is some common work to be done by constructors.  In my haste to make example lean, I did not make this obvious.  I edited OP to make this more clear.