# Optional and variably ordered function arguments with C++17

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to improve the constructor of a serial port class. At the moment there are many overloads to handle different scenarios (port, baudrate, data bits, parity, open on creation, callbacks etc.). To allow the user of this class to pass only the parameters he/she needs in an arbitrary order, I started as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct has_type;

template <typename T, typename... Us>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<Us...>> : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Us>...> {};

template <typename ...UnorderedArgs>
std::string getPort(std::tuple<UnorderedArgs...> arg_set)
{
    if constexpr (has_type<std::string, std::tuple<UnorderedArgs...>>::value)
        return std::get<std::string &&>(std::move(arg_set));
    else
        return "NotSet";
}

class SerialPort
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    SerialPort(Args ...args) :
        SerialPort(std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(args)...))
    {}

    template <typename ...UnorderedArgs>
    SerialPort(std::tuple<UnorderedArgs...> arg_set) :
        SerialPort(getPort(std::move(arg_set)))
    {}

    SerialPort(const std::string &port) // [X]
    {
        std::cout << "SerialPort " << port << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string port = "/dev/tty";
    SerialPort sp(1, port); // without 1 the compiler would use [X]
    return 0;
}
```

This code sets the port to `NotSet`, so the part with `if constexpr` is not working as intended. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Hint: what's the type of `arg_set`?

Comment: I call this kind of code an "rvalue reference overdose". Basically a total oversaturation of  rvalue references, for no useful reason whatsoever, and no apparent purpose. Even after straightening out the asked-about problem, it appears that the shown code will end up using an rvalue reference to a destroyed object (the function parameter). Hillarity ensues. As far as I can tell, every usage of `std::move` here is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I think the move in `SerialPort(std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(args)...))` kills it, as it turns `std::string` into `std::string&&` and `std::is_same<std::string, std::string&&>::value == false`

Comment: [c-how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561407/c-how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads) might interest you, or other alternative to simulate named parameter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It is doing weird things, but I don't actually see a dead reference issue. For example the `getPort` return (if it were actually used) move-constructs a `string`. It's somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This code sets the port to `NotSet`, so the part with `if constexpr` is not working as intended. How can this be fixed?

It's a problem if references: when you check the presence of `std::string` in `has_type`, `std::string` is present but with a reference (`&&` given by `std::move()`, if I'm not wrong).

Solution: remove references

```
template <typename T, typename... Us>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<Us...>>
  : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, std::remove_reference_t<Us>>...> {};
// ..................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by Jarod42 (thanks!), this way the name `has_type` isn't correct anymore.

And maybe you need an `has_type` that detect the presence of a type checking also the references...

Maybe is better maintain the original `has_type` and use `std::remove_reference_t` invoking it

```
// ............................................VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
if constexpr (has_type<std::string, std::tuple<std::remove_reference_t<UnorderedArgs>...>>::value)
    return std::get<std::string &&>(std::move(arg_set));
else
    return "NotSet";
```

Comment: Whereas it might fix final code, it makes `has_type` to lie...

Comment: @Jarod42 - Good point. Yes, maybe is better remove references in the invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you restricting yourself to what C++ offers syntactically? This problem calls for variation on builder pattern and fluent API.

Use something like this:

```
class serial_port_options
{
    /* private fields to hold options */
public:
    serial_port_options& set_port( int );
    serial_port_options& set_baudrate( int ); 
    serial_port_options& set_data_bits( int );
    serial_port_options& set_parity( bool );
    serial_port_options& set_open_on_creation( bool ); 
    serial_port_options& set_callbacks( CALLBACK );

    int get_port() const;
    int get_baudrate() const;
    int get_data_bits() const;
    bool get_parity() const;
    bool get_open_on_creation() const;
    CALLBACK get_callbacks() const;
};

class SerialPort
{
public:
     SerialPort(const serial_port_options&);

/* other logic and public interface */
};
```

Using the above, you can build your options object:

```
serial_port_options options;
options.set_port(80).set_baudrate(65536).set_data_bits(7)
       .set_parity(false).set_open_on_creation(true);

SerialPort port(options);
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that, but it's indeed the best solution to my real problem! However, I have accepted max66's answer since it solves the specific problem from the question.