# How to reorder function parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

Look at the pseudo-c++ code below:

```
typedef *** SomeType1;
typedef *** SomeType2;
typedef *** SomeType3;

void BFunc(SomeType1& st1, SomeType2& st2, SomeType3& st3)
{
    /*some work*/;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void AFunc(T1& p1, T2& p2, T3& p3)
{
    BFunc(???);
}
```

There are two functions with parameters. The parameters count larger than three, but for simplicity for example let it would be three.

The `Afunc` - it is the templated function that have the same parameters count as the `BFunc` plus the parameters have the same types as the `BFunc` parameters. But (!) the sequence on the parameters of `BFunc` can (or cannot) be different. For example:

```
BFunc(int, double, char)

AFunc<double, int, char>
AFunc<int, double, char>
AFunc<char, double, int>
AFunc<char, int, double>
...
```

So how to reorder parameters inside `AFunc` for calling `BFunc` with correct parameters sequence?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on *why* `AFunc` should be allowed to specify its arguments in any order?  Is that flexibility really necessary?

Comment: These parameters, are they guaranteed to be unique?  ie, `BFunc` will never have two parameters with the same type?

Comment: @0x5453, its a long story. I want to add the ability for users of my library to set up lambda-handlers with custom parameters sequence and count. With count I can deal in some way, but with sequence - I dont have any idea how to deal with it.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes - parameter guaranted to be unique. Yes, BFunc will never have two parameters with same type

Comment: Related to [how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561407/c-how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `std::get` to fetch a value by its type from a `tuple` and `std::tie` to bundle your arguments into a `tuple` of references.

Obviously, this only works if your argument types are unique.

Make sure `std::get` uses a reference type to avoid unnecessary copies.

```
#include <tuple>

// arbitrary argument types
struct SomeType1{};
struct SomeType2{};
struct SomeType3{};

void BFunc(SomeType1& st1, SomeType2& st2, SomeType3& st3)
{
    /*some work*/;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void AFunc(T1& p1, T2& p2, T3& p3)
{
    // Make a tuple of references to all the arguments
    auto tuple = std::tie(p1, p2, p3);

    // Find the right arguments in the tuple
    BFunc(
        std::get<SomeType1&>(tuple), 
        std::get<SomeType2&>(tuple), 
        std::get<SomeType3&>(tuple));
}

int main()
{
    SomeType1 t1;
    SomeType2 t2;
    SomeType3 t3;

    AFunc(t1,t2,t3);
    AFunc(t1,t3,t2);
    AFunc(t2,t1,t3);
    AFunc(t2,t3,t1);
    AFunc(t3,t1,t2);
    AFunc(t3,t2,t1);
}
```

Try it here : https://godbolt.org/z/7Gdc5qozW

Comment: I'm sure there is a clever solution to generalize this to generate the right `std::tie` and sequence `std::get` from a function pointer type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Fairly simple. `template<typename... Args> auto wrap(void(*fun)(Args&...)) { return [fun](auto & args...) { auto tuple = std::tie(args...); fun(std::get<Args&>(tuple)...); }; }`

Comment: @Caleth, in your code the tuple - is the tuple of values or references?